# WCF web service with two factor authentication and BizTalk

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-security, biztalk-2010

Since the beginning of a project we've been working on, I've been under the assumption that we would be able built a WCF web service that utilized two factor authentication using transport level client certificates and message level user name password following the WS-Security.  Our plan was to implement message level authentication which we've done, and add the requirement of client certificates once we were able to implement our own certificate authority.

Message level authentication has worked well for some time, and now we're able to start implementing client certificates.  We've generated a client certificate and we're trying to set this up in BizTalk, which only appears to let us choose either client certificate or username. Security modes include None, Transport, Message, Transport with Message Credentials, and Transport Credentials Only.   I choose Transport with Message Credentials, as that seems to most closely match what I'm after, but the Transport security option is disabled.

Is it possible to leverage both client certificates AND username/password?

[image]

Comment: You would have to create a custom behaviour to achieve this I think.   See here an article (non BizTalk) about dual layer of authentication that may help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabs/archive/2013/05/05/10349529.aspx

Comment: I'm still trying to get this working. In a non-Biztalk environment, your comment works. Basically it comes down to configuring the receive location with a customBinding like so: 
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomCDARequestEndpointBinding">                    
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding> however, BizTalk's customBinding config, has no  `httpsTransport` Binding Element Extension

Comment: So now, how do you get the BizTalk ports to allow the `httpsTransport` Binding Element Extension which is the key to getting this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add another answer just to keep the history of what doesn't work in this question.

That being said, I finally got it to work through customBinding. This time I've triple checked that IIS is requiring Client Certificates :)

It involved creating custom bindings on the Receive Location of one BizTalk Application and the Send Port of another, why? Because our project involves one Biztalk App sending to another.

So, to get it all to work I had to:

**Receive Location (receiving application)**

- Use the WCF Publishing wizard in Visual Studio to republish the the Receiving application using the "WCF-CustomIsolated". I wanted a fresh start and wanted to let BizTalk/Visual Studio do their thing instead of guessing.

[image]

- I went and edited the Receive Location in the the BizTalk Admin console.
- Set the textMessageEncoding messageVersion attribute to Soap11 because that's what we've been using
- **removed** the `httpTransport` binding element, because if you don't do this, you can't add the `httpsTransport` element which is require
- added the `security` element. At this point, it looked like so (order of elements matters)

[image]

- the `security` element has an attribute called `authenticationMode` which was switched to UserNameOverTransport. Despite the name, this is what allowed the UserName to be sent along with the Message. Everything else in `security` was left with the defaults

[image]

- the `httpsTransport` has an attribute named `requireClientCertificate` this was set to "true" everything else was left with the defaults.

[image]

- then added the behaviors we required, which was pretty straight forward and after that, the receive location was done.

**Send Port (sending application)**

This was nearly the same as the Receive, but just on a Send Port instead of a Receive location.

- on the Binding Tab, I repeat the exact steps as outlined for the Receive Location
- Behavior tab I added the Behavior extension called `clientCredentials` and in the ClientCertificate element set up the the following values, which just grab the client cert that is in the **Current User Store for the service account that your Send Port runs as**.
- Credentials tab I entered the UserName credentials that were previously entered in the Security tab of the WCF-BasicHttp adapter send port.

[image]

Once this is all done, the 2 applications should now be able to talk to each other using both client certs and UserName authentication.

See my answer to this question as to what this basically translates to in a non-BizTalk WCF service. [How to supply both UserName and Client Certificate in WCF client (why does this example work)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341899/how-to-supply-both-username-and-client-certificate-in-wcf-client-why-does-this)

And don't forget to restart your host instances.

**Edit - Bonus** if you end up exporting/deploying to a different server, even if you export and import/install the Web Directory separately, you'll probably get an IIS saying it can't find the endpoint for MyService/Myservice.svc thinking the receive port/location are disabled. However, it's because it's now a WCF-CustomIsolated. The solution: open the .svc file for the service that is published and change the `Factory` attribute from `BasicHttpWebServiceHostFactory` to `CustomWebServiceHostFactory`

Answer (score 0):

The client certificate can be applied on the Endpoint Identity of the send port that is using the WCF-BasicHttp adapter, this is the Transport layer (Client Cert) of security. Then in the security tab you have shown in your included screenshot, you provide the message-layer security, which would be the username/password combo.

Here's a screenshot of the identity config. You need to fill out both the top (Service Identity) and the bottom sections (Client Identity)

EDIT: **This answer is not correct, I had my settings wrong and it "worked" but not for this reason**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why it worked then?  Did you actually achieve both password and client certificate authentication?

Comment: You're really going to make me admit that in IIS I had Client certificates set to "Ignore"? That's why I put that is "worked" in quotation marks above :( Jeremy needs to revoke this answer.